# Database architecture - split vs. union vs.?

Tags: database, architecture, split

Got an interesting scenario I'd like to run past you guys re: DB architecture.

There will be two entities:

- Application: This is more or less the core of the app we are building.  It has a start and end date along with about 15 other properties.
- CalendarEvent: This a less used entity.  It has a start and end date with maybe 3 other properties.

The app we're building is mostly concerned with the applications.  There will be a calendar page where both applications and events are listed however.  Given the similarities between the entities (start and end dates) and the fact that there will be a page where they will both be listed, how would you cut this?

Ideas:

- Have an event table w/ start date, end date & type (application or calendarevent).  Have an application table which references the event table.  Have a calendarevent table which references the event table?
- Keep the tables seperate and use union in queries where both entities are required

Thanks in advance,
Alex

EDIT: 
Leaning to towards the idea of having a "Period" table w/ start date and end date.  Then both the "Application" and "CalendarEvent" tables can have a foreign key reference to a record in the period table.

Comment: I don't follow your naming logic, what IS an 'application' in this context?

Comment: In this context an "application" entity will represent an application to use a certain location at a certain time.  It's very specialised and has a fair amount of info attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option seems more scalable, as you can eventually add more **types** to the events.

The only drawback on this is the joining/loss of foreign key, but if this is not an issue, go with this design. But using the correct indexes should allow for good performance.

Me thinks, that using a union, you would have to specify the type in any case to distinguish between the 2 tables.

Comment: When you mention the drawback of the joining/loss of foriegn key - do you simply mean that it is less efficient to query across related tables?